# what's the difference between using the array name and not using the array name in jSON parsing

Tags: php, json, arrays

What is the difference that you can expect here in jSON parsing?

```
 "questionArray": [
        {
            "quizID": "1",
            "questionNumber": "1",
            "question": "bbbbbb",
            "correctAnswer": "bbb",
            "image": "jhhh.jpg",
            "animDescription": "nn",
            "option1": "nn",
            "option2": "nn",
            "option3": "nn",
            "option4": "nn"
        },
```

and

```
[
    {
        "quizID": "1",
        "questionNumber": "1",
        "question": "bbbbbb",
        "correctAnswer": "bbb",
        "image": "jhhh.jpg",
        "animDescription": "nn",
        "option1": "nn",
        "option2": "nn",
        "option3": "nn",
        "option4": "nn"
    },
```

Comment: difference is one identifier. `responseText.questionArrray[0].quizID` vs `responseText[0].quizID`

Comment: One reason you might see it done the first way is that some JSON parsers will barf if they see a top-level array.

Comment: what do you mean by a top-level array?  @jjm

Comment: @darshfify for example, this string parses as an array containing a single object: `'[{"foo":"bar"}]'`, and might break parsers that expect an object as the root element, like: `'{"array": [ { "foo": "bar"}]}'`.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not valid JSON in itself. What you probably mean is this:

```
{
    "questionArray": [
            {
                "quizID": "1",
                "questionNumber": "1",
                "question": "bbbbbb",
                "correctAnswer": "bbb",
                "image": "jhhh.jpg",
                "animDescription": "nn",
                "option1": "nn",
                "option2": "nn",
                "option3": "nn",
                "option4": "nn"
            },
...
```

which results in an object with the property `questionArray`, which contains an array, while the second JSON string results in just this array.